# Disable Quickfix from opening a new pane

Tags: vim, neovim

When I'm developing in Go, vim-go uses quickfix to alert me to errors. It's great and everything, but occasionally it will pop up a window with the source and the exact line of the error. Many times this squashes all my panes and I almost have to restart vim to fix everything. It's *very* annoying.

Is there a way I can disable quickfix from doing this? The pane it opens to display the errors it found (which look like compiling/linting errors) is fine, but the opening of the actual source is obnoxious.

Thank you!

Comment: You did not mentioned which command you were using when this happened.